# I want a popup lightbox effect to show a page without refreshing from a link

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to show a link named "contact-us" in my website which when click should popup dynamically and show the contact us form so that users can simply type in their enquires and send it without refreshing the whole page

I want this to be done with the click of a button or link
I prefer to do this with html, javascript, php

---

**WORKING**

when a link is clicked the javascript and html will show the lightbox effect or similar effect which loads a page from the server say for example contactus.html and then show it in the front without refreshing the whole page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a javascript library like jquery or mootools, there are TONS of plugins( fancybox for jquery or ReMooz for MooTools for example) that will do this for you. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: please if you could give an example otherwise dont waste time to send me answers. It is not going to help us both

Comment: What would you like an example of? I suggested a couple plugins for libraries that you didn't specify if you were using or not. It would actually help us both if you were more verbose in your OP.

Comment: sorry I missed out those in brackets. I will go through those and come back to you

Comment: If you decide to go through the jQuery route, and use FancyBox, here is a JS Snippet that will open a site in an 800x480px iFrame with a nice elastic animation:

    $('#linkID').fancybox({
        'width': '800',
        'height' '480',
        'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
 'transitionOut': 'elastic',
 'type':'iframe'
    });

Answer (score 2):

Checkout http://fancybox.net/ which is a jQuery Lightbox tool. On the fancybox page checkout the IFrame example I think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to you [jqueryui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) with many features